# Does any TV work with Ubuntu TV or only specific ones (Hardware requirements)

Tags: ubuntu-tv

I have a 1080p TV and was wondering if there is some kind of specific hardware for Ubuntu TV or any technical specifications for it that I should know. Will it work correctly with a 1080p TV with HDMI or does it work with only a group of TVs.

What are the hardware requirements to use Ubuntu TV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still in its infancy but "[Ubuntu TV](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/112601-canonical-outs-ubuntu-tv-brave-or-stupid) comes with a `box office built right in` that gives you access to movie rentals, YouTube, and other online media outlets". So you need to buy a new TV with the Ubuntu hardware in it if you are talking about an actual TV with actually Ubuntu on it. I bet they'll also start making settop boxes since then you can use it in any TV (that has the correct connections).

[Video about Ubuntu TV](http://bartongeorge.net/2012/01/13/mark-shuttleworth-part-one-ubuntutv/)

You can also install a [development version of Ubuntu TV](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-tv-right-now-via-ppa/) on your own PC so you can ofcourse use your netbook, notebook or PC to stream it to your TV (ie. your system sends the signal to your PC). But I would not call that Ubuntu TV as it was announced by Mark Shuttleworth.

Comment: I would not bet on Ubuntu TV being in set-top boxes if I was you. This is a quote from the Ubuntu web site: "It integrates broadcast, time shift, online box office, personal cloud, apps and disk media experiences - all without wires, connectors or more boxes. It really is just the TV."

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to run Ubuntu TV with any TV by installing it onto a computer and connecting it to your television; however, Canonical is working with TV vendors to have Ubuntu TV software built directly into the unit so an additional PC or set-top-box wouldn't be needed.

Comment: That is exactly what was confusing me. Was it build in, was it with a PC.

Comment: Can you provide evidence to back up the claim you make in that first sentence? From the Ubuntu web site I see these statements: "Everything that you want in a TV. In a TV." And, "Just TV. No wires. No boxes."

Comment: Sure. Right now Ubuntu TV is in development, but it can still be installed and tested on almost any machine. It basically replaces Unity 2D. Check out this post on OMG! Ubuntu! for more information: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-tv-right-now-via-ppa/